# DispatchQueue.main and DispatchQueue.global are same in swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

`Dispatchqueue.main` runs on main thread and `global` runs on background thread, is that correct? If not, then what’s the difference?

Comment: There is too much content on this topic on the internet. Make sure to to some research before you post a question on the Stackoverflow please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> `DispatchQueue.main` runs on main thread and `global` runs on background thread is that correct?

Yes, the [`main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1781006-main) queue is a serial queue that runs dispatched tasks on the main thread.

A [`global`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global) queue avails itself of multiple “background threads”. Each of the global queues (one for each “quality of service”, QoS) is a concurrent queue whose dispatched tasks run on one of the background threads which are drawn from a pool of worker threads of the appropriate QoS.

---

See the legacy [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) for description of the differences between the various types of dispatch queues. The document uses the old Objective-C syntax, but the general concepts are equally applicable in Swift.

Comment: What is the difference between queue and thread?

Comment: Threads are low-level objects on which our code actually runs. But we practically never write our own `Thread`-based code, anymore, because it is complicated and is surprisingly inefficient. We use queues, which are high-level objects that give us a multithreaded interface that abstracts us away from the details and complexities of writing threading code correctly. E.g., it’s more efficient because rather than spinning up a new thread every time you need one, it grabs and idle thread from the thread pool. It’s simpler because we don’t need to worry about autorelease pools or the like, anymore.

Comment: See [Moving away from threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW8) section of the aforementioned _Concurrency Programming Guide._

Comment: FWIW, queues abstracted us away from the details of threads. That was a great improvement, but it introduced the complexity of “closures” (what we used to call “blocks” in Objective-C) where code in a closure would run later than code appeared later in the same function, sometimes making it hard to reason about our code. So, last year, they introduced [Swift concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html), which takes this a step further, allowing us to express asynchronous code in a more logical fashion, abstracting us further away from threads and queues.